# What's in teamcity custom_script.cmd

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

I'm trying to dig into the depths of teamcity to get a better understanding of what its doing under the hood(and improve my own build knowledge). I noticed that when I run a build step it then executes its own .cmd which I presume wraps up the msbuild scripts. The problem is that whenever I look in the directory specified the file doesn't exist as I'm guessing it creates, executes then deletes almost instantly. Any suggestions on how to access the file? or what's inside?

Starting:D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\agentTmp\custom_script5990675507156014131.cmd

Comment: Your question will be easier to discover is you remove the (presumably) random number from the title. If the file doesn't persist during the build you could look at the arguments msbuild was started with using e.g. Process Explorer, though that only tells you the arguments in the cmd file, not the whole content.

Comment: I have updated title as suggested. I tried having a look at process explorer but I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 1):

A temporary file is created by TeamCity when you run add a Command Line Build Step with "Custom script" as runner.

The content of this file would be the `Custom script` you specified inside the user interface.
[image: Custom Script build step]

The produced output would be:

```
Step 1/1: Command Line (1s)
Starting: D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\agentTmp\custom_script2362934300799611461.cmd
in directory: D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c72dca7a7355b5de
Hello World
Process exited with code 0
```

Comment: This seems very likely but I can't verify 100%. From your example we can see the echo but I would like to also see the switches & supplied arguments for example.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is wondering about this still, you can force echo back on.
Put as the first thing in the custom script

```
@echo on
```

this will undo the silent commands teamcity defaults to.

Comment: Thank you! It's really perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

I looked around for a while but there seems to be no configuration variable in TeamCity allowing to keep generated files. Now if the commands executed take some time, e.g. more than a couple of seconds, you could just open the temp directory in explorer and start hitting F5 (refresh) from the moment a build is started until you see the .cmd file appear, then be quick and right-click it and select 'Edit' to open it in a text editor. If that is too hard you can try with the solution presented [here](https://superuser.com/questions/226828/how-to-monitor-a-folder-and-trigger-a-command-line-action-when-a-file-is-created): create a Powershell script with code like this:

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\agentTmp"
$watcher.Filter = "*.cmd"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  
$action = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
            Add-content "D:\log.txt" -value (Get-Content $path)
          }    
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
while ($true) {sleep 1}
```

and run it. When the build starts and creates a cmd file, the powershell script will copy the content to d:\log.txt. This will still not work for very short-lived scripts though. In that case I'd just make the script last longer by adding something like

```
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 -w 1000 > NUL
```

which will make it last at least 5 seconds.